# Can not run mysqltuner

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-10.04, mysqltuner

I am running Ubuntu 10.04 LTS and I'm trying to run mysqltuner but it won't work. I downloaded the script and made it executable and then i typed ./mysqltuner.pl but it gave error

```
./mysqltuner.pl: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
./mysqltuner.pl: line 4: `<!DOCTYPE html>'
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: There are quite a few of these, please tell us which mysqltuner.pl you are using. This one? https://github.com/rackerhacker/MySQLTuner-perl/blob/master/mysqltuner.pl

Comment: Looks like you downloaded an HTML file and not an perl program.

Comment: I download from this wget http://mysqltuner.com/mysqltuner.pl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably didn't get the actual script.

Try to download https://raw.github.com/rackerhacker/MySQLTuner-perl/master/mysqltuner.pl instead